# While running weditor getting 407 Proxy Authentication Required error

Tags: python-3.x, android-uiautomator

Always getting proxy authentication error although I have done proxy setup. Below is the error which I am getting.
Weditor is a python package - https://pypi.org/project/weditor/

```
PS C:\workspace\xyzz\repo\gerrit\ver-v3fw-sem-tests> weditor
listening on http://10.275.34.219:17310
[I 230502 12:08:16 web:2271] 304 GET / (::1) 6.30ms
[I 230502 12:08:17 shell:47] Started drain subprocess stdout in thread
02T063629Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=eb58rwewrds352350502eea1c7d63b0e86ac7150bd64f9f52fsdfs243416c06cd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=10rwewr564347649&response-co
ntent-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Datx-agent_0.10.0_linux_386.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSErro
r('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
[E 230502 12:08:26 web:2271] 500 POST /api/v1/connect (::1) 4645.09ms
```